# Packer - RHEL8 - VMWare-ISO - OpenScap --- SSH connect fails due to password reset required

Tags: packer, rhel8

I'm trying to create a RHEL8 Template with OpenScap Security Profile enabled.
Unfortunately it fails due to a required password reset after activating the security profile.

I've tried to login via ssh certificate, but still get the same issue, because even for ssh-key login a password change is required.

Hope anybody has an idea to work around this issue.

Here the code:

#### HCL

```
packer {
  required_plugins {
    vmware = {
      version = ">= 1.0.3"
      source = "github.com/hashicorp/vmware"
    }
  }
}
variable "boot_wait" {
  type    = string
  default = "15s"
}
variable "disk_size" {
  type    = string
  default = "40960"
}
variable "iso_checksum" {
  type    = string
  default = "sha256:8CB0DFACC94B789933253D5583A2FB7AFCE26D38D75BE7C204975FE20B7BDF71"
}
variable "iso_url" {
  type    = string
  default = "D:\\isos\\rhel-8.6-x86_64-dvd.iso"
}
variable "memsize" {
  # type    = int
  default = 2048
}
variable "numvcpus" {
  # type    = int
  default = 2
}
variable "ssh_password" {
  type    = string
  default = "admin123"
}
variable "ssh_ppk" {
  type    = string
  default = "E:\\Workspace\\Packer\\RHEL8\\ssh\\id_rsa"
}
variable "ssh_username" {
  type    = string
  default = "admin"
}
variable "vm_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "RHEL8-x86_64"
}

source "vmware-iso" "rhel8-template" {
  boot_command            = ["<tab><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>inst.text inst.ks=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/ks.cfg<enter><wait>"]
  boot_wait               = "${var.boot_wait}"
  cpus                    = "${var.numvcpus}"
  memory                  = "${var.memsize}"
  disk_adapter_type       = "nvme"
  disk_size               = "${var.disk_size}"
  disk_type_id            = "0"
  guest_os_type           = "rhel8-64"
  headless                = false
  http_directory          = "http"
  iso_checksum            = "${var.iso_checksum}"
  iso_url                 = "${var.iso_url}"
  shutdown_command        = "echo 'admin123'|sudo -S /sbin/halt -h -p"
  #ssh_password           = "${var.ssh_password}"
  remote_private_key_file = "${var.ssh_ppk}"
  ssh_port                = 22
  ssh_timeout             = "30m"
  ssh_username            = "${var.ssh_username}"
  ssh_certificate_file    = "${var.ssh_ppk}"
  vm_name                 = "${var.vm_name}"
  vmx_data = {
    "ethernet0.addressType" = "generated"
    "ethernet0.present"     = "TRUE"
    "ethernet0.virtualDev"  = "vmxnet3"
    "virtualHW.version"     = "15"
  }
}
build {
  sources = ["source.vmware-iso.rhel8-template"]

}
```

#### Kickstart

```
cdrom

lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard --xlayouts='de (nodeadkeys)'
timezone --utc Europe/Berlin

network --onboot yes --device eth0 --bootproto dhcp --noipv6

rootpw --iscrypted $6$3AKU...c.w0
rootpw --lock

user --name=admin --groups=wheel --password=$6$3AN....c.w0 --iscrypted
sshkey --username=admin "ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...QteU="

firewall --enabled --ssh

authselect select sssd
selinux --enforcing

bootloader --location=mbr --append="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet" --password=$6$zCPaBA...s5qNto0
zerombr

clearpart --linux --initlabel
part /boot --fstype=xfs --size=512
part pv.01 --grow --size=1
volgroup rhel --pesize=4096 pv.01

logvol / --fstype=xfs --name=root --vgname=rhel --size=10240 --grow
logvol /home --fstype=xfs --name=home --vgname=rhel --size=1024 --fsoptions="nodev"
logvol /tmp --fstype=xfs --name=tmp --vgname=rhel --size=1024 --fsoptions="nodev,noexec,nosuid"
logvol /var/tmp --fstype=xfs --name=var_tmp --vgname=rhel --size=1024 --fsoptions="nodev,nosuid,noexec"
logvol /var --fstype=xfs --name=var --vgname=rhel --size=3072
logvol /var/log --fstype=xfs --name=var_log --vgname=rhel --size=1024
logvol /var/log/audit --fstype=xfs --name=var_log_audit --vgname=rhel --size=512
logvol swap --name=swap --vgname=rhel --size=2016

%addon org_fedora_oscap
        content-type = scap-security-guide
        profile = xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_cis
%end

%packages

@^minimal-environment
kexec-tools
python38
# Exclude unnecessary firmwares
-iwl*firmware
-aic94xx-firmware*
-alsa-*

%end 

reboot --eject
```

#### Error

```
==> vmware-iso.rhel8-template: Error waiting for SSH: Packer experienced an authentication error when trying to connect via SSH. This can happen if your username/password are wrong. You may want to double-check your credentials as part of your debugging process. original error: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none], no supported methods remain
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the vmware tag: QUESTIONS ABOUT SERVER ADMINISTRATION ARE OFF-TOPIC. General VMWare questions may be asked on superuser.com or serverfault.com.

Comment: It’s not about VMWare, and the result would be the same on kvm

Answer (score 0):

It's because of "rootpw --lock"

Comment: Seeing that you did not finish in any punctuation and because there is no explanation whatsoever in your answer, I assume that you are still [edit]ing to add details, an explanation of how the problem is caused, a solution and an explanation why the solution helps.

Comment: No, it’s not. Login is tried with admin user. As soon as oscap is commented out, everything works